# What is the equivalent of the java "super" keyword in PHP 5?

Tags: php

I want to `extend` a `class` : `class figure extends model_base { ... }` , and in the constructor of the class children ( here it is figure )

I want to call its parent's `constructor` : in java we do it by writing `super(arguments);`

So how to call parent's constructor in PHP ?

Comment: `parent::__construct($args)`. For more information about `parent` [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need is

```
<?php
class BaseClass {
   function __construct() {
       print "In BaseClass constructor\n";
   }
}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {
   function __construct() {
       parent::__construct(); // this will call your parent constructor
       print "In SubClass constructor\n";
   }
}

$obj = new BaseClass();
$obj = new SubClass();
?>
```

Please read: [Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: Is it mandatory to give the constructor name ( both for baseclass and subclass ) to `__construct()` ? Or can I name it whatever I like ?

Comment: @pheromix  u have give name as __construct() bcz ,                 The __construct() function creates a new SimpleXMLElement object,
which returns an object.

Answer (score 5):

```
parent::__construct($argument);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is **parent** in PHP

```
Java - Super

PHP  - Parent
```